# select data from last 2 rows sql

Tags: java, sql, select, jdbc-odbc

Im using an `odbc-jdbc bridge` in my project and I need select 2 pieces of data from the `database` and save the data to 2 `variables` on the `java` side of my application. Here is an example of my table.

```
SITE_ID ------- DEV_ID ------- SCHEDULE_TIME ------- VALUE_ENUM ------- IDX
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               3000           09:30:00              1                    1
1               3000           11:30:00              0                    2
1               3000           12:00:00              1                    3
1               3000           14:00:00              0                    4
1               3000           18:30:00              1                    5
1               3000           20:30:00              0                    6
1               4000           05:00:00              1                    1 
1               4000           13:30:00              0                    2
1               4000           16:30:00              1                    3
1               4000           18:30:00              0                    4
```

What I want to do is `select SCHEDULE_TIME` for the last 2 `IDX`'s where `DEV_ID` is `3000`, so I would like to save `18:30:00 and 20:30:00` in a variables, some examples of statements Ive tried are:

```
select SCHEDULE_TIME from ARRAY_BAC_SCH_Schedule order by IDX desc limit 1 where DEV_ID = 3000
select SCHEDULE_TIME from ARRAY_BAC_SCH_Schedule order by IDX desc limit (1,1) where DEV_ID = 3000

SELECT TOP 1 SCHEDULE_TIME FROM ARRAY_BAC_SCH_Schedule WHERE DEV_ID = 3000 ORDER BY IDX DESC
```

Right now Im just worrying about how to get the select statement to work in Query tool before I implement it in the java side. Thanks, Beef.

Comment: get the select statement to work in Query tool? what do you mean ?

Comment: @Wadih M.: Likely referring to the query tool provided with the database. Beef wants to test the query before implementing it in Java.

Comment: As Terrell said you will need to check what kind of database are you using because the SQL to run will be different depending on it.

Other option (with worst performance) could be to select all results  ordering using the `IDX` and iterate to retrieve 2 rows (as a maximum).

Comment: its through Delta Controls so Im not entirely sure which kind of database it is, Im pretty sure its just a SQL DB cause all the other lines Ive used for other tasks work fine, and any other DB I have had experience with has always been sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server you should use

```
SELECT TOP 2 SCHEDULE_TIME from (select SCHEDULE_TIME FROM ARRAY_BAC_SCH_Schedule WHERE DEV_ID = 3000 ORDER BY IDX DESC) as inner
```

like Hemal told you.

Be careful with queries like

```
select TOP 2 SCHEDULE_TIME FROM ARRAY_BAC_SCH_Schedule WHERE DEV_ID = 3000 ORDER BY IDX DESC
```

because that is wrong. SQL Server does the top and then the order.

In PostgreSQL or MySQL you should use limit and the end of the query. The limit is after the where part.

In Oracle you should use rownum inside the where part.

Comment: with the top SQL Server statement I get an error: `<eb1>Expected lexical element not found: FROM
State: 37000; Native: 1015; Origin: [Delta Controls Inc.][Delta Controls ODBC Driver]</eb1>`

Comment: "inner" is not a good name... try this:
SELECT TOP 2 [SCHEDULE_TIME] from (select [SCHEDULE_TIME] FROM [ARRAY_BAC_SCH_Schedule] WHERE [DEV_ID] = 3000 ORDER BY [IDX] DESC) as [schTimesFiltered]

Comment: I still get the same error, Im not that new to sql I can usually figure out queries on my own, but since Ive been working with this database I run into a lot of errors I dont recognize

Comment: But, is it a SQL Server? Which version?

Comment: Im not exactly sure, is there a way to find out? or just ask someone that knows

Comment: If it is a SQL Server with `select @@version` you will get the version. If it is not you will get an error :)

Comment: I usually do all my sql work with sql server 2008 and management studio, but I could not get management studio to connect to a machine data source so instead I use Query Tool(using odbc) V6.1 to do all my queries, and I got an error with the select @@version

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3702/discussion-between-davideg-and-beef)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something. Is there a reason you wouldn't just run:

```
select SCHEDULE_TIME from ARRAY_BAC_SCH_Schedule order by IDX desc limit 2 where DEV_ID = 3000
```

This should return 2 rows, containing 20:30:00 and 18:30:00.

Comment: when i run that line I get error saying Unexpected extra token: limit

Answer (score 1):

if it is `mysql` then

```
 select SCHEDULE_TIME from ARRAY_BAC_SCH_Schedule where DEV_ID = 3000 order by IDX desc limit 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
SELECT TOP 2 * from (select SCHEDULE_TIME FROM ARRAY_BAC_SCH_Schedule WHERE DEV_ID = 3000 ORDER BY IDX DESC) as inner
```

Comment: With this one I get an error saying: Expected lexical element not found: FROM

Answer (score 1):

The specifics will vary a little based on your DB, but your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 2 SCHEDULE_TIME 
FROM ARRAY_BAC_SCH_Schedule
WHERE DEV_ID = 3000
ORDER BY IDX Desc
```

Or, on one line:

```
SELECT TOP 2 SCHEDULE_TIME FROM ARRAY_BAC_SCH_Schedule WHERE DEV_ID = 3000 ORDER BY IDX Desc
```

Comment: With this one I get an error saying: Expected lexical element not found: FROM

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with subquerys:

```
select * from array_bac_sch_schedule where (value_enum,idx) in (select value_enum,idx from array_bac_sch_schedule where dev_id=3000) order by schedule_time desc limit 2;
```

I took value_enum and idx as primary key.